# Compute shared hstore key names in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hstore

If I have a table with an HSTORE column:

```
CREATE TABLE thing (properties hstore);
```

How could I query that table to find the hstore key names that exist in *every row*.

For example, if the table above had the following data:

```
               properties                    
-------------------------------------------------
"width"=>"b", "height"=>"a"
"width"=>"b", "height"=>"a", "surface"=>"black"
"width"=>"c"
```

How would I write a query that returned `'width'`, as that is the only key that occurs in each row?

`skeys()` will give me all the property keys, but I'm not sure how to aggregate them so I only have the ones that occur in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual gets us most of the way there, but not all the way... way down at the bottom of http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/hstore.html under the heading "Statistics", they describe a way to count keys in an hstore.

If we adapt that to your sample table above, you can compare the counts to the # of rows in the table.

```
SELECT key
    FROM (SELECT (each(properties)).key FROM thing1) AS stat
    GROUP BY key
        HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from thing1)
    ORDER BY key;
```

If you want to find the opposite (all those keys that are *not* in every row of your table), just change the = to < and you're in business!